# Oracle sql how to get start and end dates of weeks between two dates

Tags: oracle

I want to get the start and end days of every week between two dates. The dates's format is dd/mm/yyy hh24:mi:ss. I need the weeks in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss because I have to calculate the days and hours between the start and end day of the week with the times

I wrote this statement

```
WITH 
date_range AS (

SELECT
            pdm.des_comercial serie,
                pdm.id_material codserie,
                ri.id_accion intervencion,
                TO_CHAR(NVL(ri.fecha_salida_rev, SYSDATE), 'dd/mm/RRRR') fecha1,
                to_char((CASE
                    WHEN ri.fecha_salida_rev > TO_DATE('18/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') THEN TO_DATE('18/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                    WHEN ri.fecha_salida_Rev IS NULL THEN TO_DATE('18/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                    ELSE ri.fecha_salida_Rev
                END),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') fechasalida,
                to_char((CASE
                    WHEN ri.fecha_entrada_rev < TO_DATE('01/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') THEN TO_DATE('01/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                    ELSE ri.fecha_entrada_Rev
                END),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') fechaentrada
                ,
                ri.cod_taller_rev,
                ri.COD_MATRICULA,
                ri.fecha_entrada_rev start_date,
                ri.fecha_salida_rev end_date
            FROM
                r_intervencion ri,
                planificador.pl_dh_material pdm
            WHERE
                ri.id_accion = ri.amortizada_por
                AND ri.causa_entrada = 1
                AND ri.tipo_accion = 1
                AND pdm.id_material = ri.cod_serie
                AND pdm.hasta = 99999999
                AND ri.ID_ACCION = 'IM4'
                AND ri.fecha_salida_rev BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('18/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                 ),

semanas AS (            


SELECT  LEVEL "Week"

     ,to_char(to_date(start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + (7 * (LEVEL - 1)),'IW') startweek

       ,to_char(to_date(start_date ,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')+ (7 * (LEVEL - 1)),'IW') + 6 endweek

       ,TO_CHAR(start_date + (7 * (LEVEL - 1)),'IW') "Iso Week",
       serie,
       codserie,
       intervencion,
       cod_taller_rev,
       cod_matricula,
       fechaentrada,
       fechasalida,
       start_date,
       end_date

FROM   date_range
CONNECT  BY LEVEL <= (to_char(To_date(end_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'IW') - to_char(To_date(start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'IW')) / 7 + 1 

) 

SELECT startweek,
endweek,
to_date(endweek,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - to_date(startweek,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  dias,
serie,
codserie,
intervencion,
cod_taller_rev,
cod_matricula,
start_Date,
end_date,
fechaentrada,
fechasalida,
rd.descripcion
FROM semanas,r_depositos rd
WHERE cod_taller_rev = rd.cod_deposito
```

When I execute it, I get

Query execution failed

```
SQL Error [1840] [22008]: ORA-01840: ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format
```

The error is in

```
 ,to_char(to_date(start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + (7 * (LEVEL - 1)),'IW') startweek

       ,to_char(to_date(start_date ,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')+ (7 * (LEVEL - 1)),'IW') + 6 endweek
```

How can I get the startweek and endweek with the format dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss

EDITED

```
start_date                   end_date

20/05/2019 20:00:00         05/06/2019  08:00:00
```

weeks

```
20/05/2019 20:00:00 26/05/2019  -> 6 days and xxx hours
27/05/2019          02/06/2019 -> 7 days
03/06/2019          05/06/2019 08:00:00 -> 3 days and xxx hours
```

I need to calculate the difference in days and hours for each week.

```
For example between 20/05/2019 20:00:00 and 26/05/2019
and last one between 03/06/2019 and 05/06/2019 08:00:00
```

My issue is with the calculation

```
to_date(endweek,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - to_date(startweek,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  dias,

endweek and startweek have to have dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss
```

Comment: Presumably `start_date` (or `fecha_entrada_rev`) is already of data type DATE, so you should not be calling `to_date()` for that (you're doing an implicit `to_char()`, with NLS settings, which then doesn't match the format you try to use to convert back)? Your approach seems to be flawed: dates do not have an intrinsic human-readable format, even it your client shows them in the format you mention. If you want to do manipulation and comparison then leave them as dates - only convert to formatted strings for display.

Comment: Then, I have a question. How can I write  to_char(to_date(start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + (7 * (LEVEL - 1)),'IW') startweek without to_char because I have to extract (7*(LEVEL -1))

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `to_char(start_date + (7 * (LEVEL - 1)),'IW')` will give you the ISO week number, which you're already doing later. Maybe you want `trunc(start_date, 'IW')` to get the actual start of that week instead?

Comment: I can't do trunc(start_date) because I need to do the calculations with the start_date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'

Comment: Dates *do not have a format*. e.g. `trunc(sysdate, 'IW')` might be displayed by a client as 17-Jun-19, 2019-06-17, 2019-06-17 00:00:00, 17/06/2019 00:00:00, 06/17/2019 00:00:00 or myriad others depending on the client and NLS settings (including other languages if you use month names/abbreviations). But that has nothing to do with using a truncated date in calculations. (It would help if you provided a [mre] with sample data and results, e.g. with columns irrelevant to the question removed.)

Comment: I edited an example of data

Answer (score 0):

Your `endweek` calculation is

```
to_char(to_date(start_date ,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')+ (7 * (LEVEL - 1)),'IW') + 6 endweek
```

This attempts to add the number 6 to a character string. I suspect that what you wanted was

```
to_char(to_date(start_date ,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + (7 * (LEVEL - 1) + 6),'IW') endweek
```

Here I've moved the `+ 6` so you're adding 6 to the date value, rather than to a character string.

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is with the calculation
>
> ```
> to_date(endweek,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - to_date(startweek,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  dias,
>
> endweek and startweek have to have dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss
> ```

Oracle dates are stored in an internal format which you generally don't need to worry about. Your application or client formats the date as a string, based on its own setting or your session NLS settings.

When you do something like:

```
to_date(endweek,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

you're really doing:

```
to_date(to_char(endweek),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

and as there is no explicit format mask specified for the implicit `to_char()` call it used your current session's NLS settings. Depending on the setting it might error; or might corrupt the value - e.g. mixing YY and YYYY masks can lose the century, converting 2019 to 0019. (Given the error you are getting, your NLS settings might be unusual?).

At best you're converting the date value to a string and back to exactly the same date value, which is pointless. You aren't changing the *format* of the datem because it doesn't have one. The intermediate string does, but you aren't using that, and you can't for calculations (at least without converting back to a date as you are, which again is pointless.)

Oracle has other functions to manipulate date values, including `trunc()`, so I think you might want something like this - showing the difference in three ways, though there are others and you can format the last one however you want:

```
with date_range (start_date, end_date) as (
  -- dummy data from your example
  select to_date('20/05/2019 20:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24;MI:SS') as start_date,
    to_date('05/06/2019 08:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24;MI:SS') as end_date
  from dual
),
semanas as (            
  select level as week,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    greatest(trunc(start_date + (7 * (level - 1)), 'IW'), start_date) as start_week,
    least(trunc(start_date + (7 * level), 'IW'), end_date) as end_week
  from date_range
  connect by level <= (trunc(end_date, 'IW') - trunc(start_date, 'IW')) / 7 + 1
)
select week,
  to_char(start_week, 'IW') as iso_week,
  to_char(start_week, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as start_week,
  to_char(end_week, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as end_week,
  end_week - start_week as diff_num,
  numtodsinterval(end_week - start_week, 'DAY') as diff_interval,
  to_char(date '1999-12-31' + (end_week - start_week), 'FMDD "days" HH24 "hours"') as diff_words
from semanas;

      WEEK IS START_WEEK          END_WEEK              DIFF_NUM DIFF_INTERVAL       DIFF_WORDS      
---------- -- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ------------------- ----------------
         1 21 20/05/2019 20:00:00 27/05/2019 00:00:00 6.16666667 +06 04:00:00.000000 6 days 4 hours  
         2 22 27/05/2019 00:00:00 03/06/2019 00:00:00          7 +07 00:00:00.000000 7 days 0 hours  
         3 23 03/06/2019 00:00:00 05/06/2019 08:00:00 2.33333333 +02 08:00:00.000000 2 days 8 hours
```

As currently written the `connect by` only works properly if the `date_range` CTE generates a single value; if you actually get multiple rows back from your real query then you'll have to do a bit more work, or switch to recursive CTEs, or cross join/apply, depending on your Oracle version.